Custom Font (.ttf) added to project not available within app
I'm trying to add a custom font to my app but it doesn't appear when the app is running:

Added the files to the project



Checked the font is within the Target Membership



Added the fonts to the app plist under the "Fonts provided by application":



Checked the fonts are within the Target/ Build Phases/ Copy Bundle Resources:



Installed the fonts in the Font Book

After that, when I run the app:
for (NSString* family in [UIFont familyNames])
{
    NSLog(@"FONT FAMILY: %@", family);
    
    for (NSString* name in [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName: family])
    {
        NSLog(@"FONT:  %@", name);
    }
}

All fonts except the JetBrains ones are available. What am I missing?

Double-check everything... I just downloaded the JetBrains fonts, added them to my project - https://i.sstatic.net/VStT4.png - defined them in "Fonts provided by application" - https://i.sstatic.net/r1bzc.png - and no problems - https://i.sstatic.net/vbe6v.png ---- As a side note - no need to install the fonts in Font Book.

@DonMag is true, I created a project from scratch and the font is available. But there is no missing steps in my main project. Any ideas?

Found the answer.
Changed the "Fonts provided by application" key in the .plist file with "UIAppFonts" and the font started to work

What was the wrong key? How did Xcode not use the right key?

UIAppFonts is the correct key.  Xcode can show you English descriptions for known keys when you edit the file (in this case "Fonts provided by application"), but the raw key actually in the file should be UIAppFonts.  If you typed in the English description as the raw key, then it won't work.  If there was an accidental space or something in the key, it won't work either.
